# How to prevent click event after .focus on HTMLelement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using HTMLelement.focus at two places. One inside componentdidupdate and once in normal private method. The one inside componentdidupdate is triggering click action on the referred element. When I check the flow in debug mode, the click event is not being triggered. The one in normal private method is working fine.

How do I prevent the click after focus event?

Comment: Welcome to SO - please read the help section on how to ask questions. It's ideal if you show what you've tried so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are not using jQuery, but if you would like to use jQuery, just use jQuery focus event and off the click event on the element. Here you can see on `#second` textbox...!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#first, #second').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('clicked..!')
 });
 $('#second').on('focus', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).off('click');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="" id="first" placeholder="First">
<input type="text" name="" id="second" placeholder="second">
```

Comment: I am using React, can't use jQuery here.